# Unsubscribe/cancel all http requests when any component is destroyed

Tags: angular, rxjs

We have a lot of components that make an http request to get their data. I've been tasked with cancelling http requests when a component gets destroyed. So what I can do is go into each individual component, implement `ngOnDestroy()`, and store the http subscription as a member of the component's class, but we have too many components for me to go in and do that one by one.

Is there a way I can tell angular that when **any** component gets destroyed, cancel all its http requests?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. Chances are there are not tons of http requests hanging around waiting to be resolved (if there are you have a design problem). Go through the components and identify the calls that 1) could be waiting for a response if the component is destroyed and 2) would make sense to unsubscribe from. Then implement ngOnDestroy for that component and unsubscribe from that call (if still waiting).

Comment: @Igor I was afraid that was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to define a better subscription pattern so you don't need to unsubscribe.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  componentActive = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Watch for changes to the currently selected product
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromProduct.getCurrentProduct),
      takeWhile(() => this.componentActive)
    ).subscribe(
      currentProduct => this.displayProduct(currentProduct)
    );

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentActive = false;
  }

}
```

Notice the `takeWhile`. This ensures that any subscriptions stop when the component is destroyed.

You can find more information here: https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/ (But note that the code shown in this post is for the older version of RxJS.)

Comment: The problem is that I have to do this for every component. I need a solution to code this once and is implemented for all components. We have a lot of components that make HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes. Retrofitting patterns is not fun. So consider carefully how to make this change so you don't end up having to do it again. :-)

Comment: I ended up making a parent class and all the components extended it. A little bit easier.